# SQL query learning stuff 

Tags: sql

I want to learn SQL/TSQL queries.
Can somebody tell me how to learn it? I have learned syntax and some basics too, but I'm not finding any good stuff to make practice and learn it. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Hope you already visited http://w3schools.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like [sqlzoo](http://sqlzoo.net/), it's got a safe, interactive place to play around with the language.  There are tutorials and also practice questions you can answer and see results with.

Answer (score 3):

- Download one of the free SQL databases, for example [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/express.aspx) or [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/).
- Learn the [basics of relational databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database).
- Learn about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).
- Buy Alan Beaulieu's book [Learning SQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007272).
- Buy Kevin Kline's book [SQL In A Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596004818).
- For more advanced stuff, buy Celko's book [SQL for Smarties](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558605762).
- Read everything written by [Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/).
- Play around with [SQLzoo](http://sqlzoo.net/).
- Using examples from the above resources, start practicing.
- Write a personal application that is SQL-centric - this will give you a specific context for understanding the ideas and examples.

Answer (score 2):

Try w3schools.com!! They have the most basic stuff to get a layman started.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an interesting and interactive tutorial at http://sol.gfxile.net/galaxql.html